# What is the difference between "presume" and "preassume"?

Tags: word-usage, orthography, confusables

> **[Preassume](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/preassume)** (third-person singular simple present *preassumes*, present participle *preassuming*, simple past and past participle
> *preassumed*)
>
> (transitive) To assume in advance; to presume.
> *Wiktionary*

How does its usage differ from "presume"? Are there some fields that "preassume" is usually used but not "presume"? Does the word "preassume" come from a typo of  "presume"?

Comment: I suspect that it does (come from a typo). I've never heard of it, and googling 'preassume definition' produces 'Did you mean _presume_?'

Comment: The (common) misspelling probably derives from: **assume** "suppose to be the case, without proof."

Comment: Even if you did provide a dictionary definition, there's not much  research. And knowing "why" some native speakers say "Preassume" instead of "assume" is anyone's guess. It's impossible to give a definite answer to a question posed as this.

Comment: There _is_ evidence that it is used by some, which I'd say Wiktionary has picked up on and accepted too quickly for once. I can't see that using it is ever the least bit helpful. _Preassume_ ... assume prior to _what_? The narrative should make it clear that an assumption is made prior to some eventuality, so redundancy looks likely.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Could you please elaborate?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth When you are logically arguing something, you could either provide your assumptions as your thesis is developing, or you could (implicitly) assume things before everything is started. I would say the latter case is "preassuming" something.

Comment: I've never seen the word before.

Comment: Isn't presuming already assuming beforehand? Isn't that how we got to presuming, by pre assuming?

Comment: Elaborate on what? It's a nonstandard word. Possibly an [*eggcorn*](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/eggcorn) derived from **pre + assume**, it has the same meaning as *presume*.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Oh so it is just another "eggcorn"? This is a convincing interpretation.

Comment: I'd never seen it before, but **pre-assume** (with hyphen) is in the full OED. Sense 1 *(To consume or take previously or beforehand)* is marked "obsolete", but sense 2 *(To assume or take for granted beforehand)* has its latest citation from 1997. Note that only 3 out of the 5 cited instances for that second sense have a hyphen (the other 2 *aren't* hyphenated). But my advice to anyone not 100% confident in their command of English would be to forget about it, since hardly anyone would realise it's a "valid" word today.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Where did you get the citation data? It seems a very interesting source!

Comment: It looks like someone lumped together *assume* and *pre-judge.*  For example, preparing for a tough meeting at school: "Let's not pre-judge; there's no point in assuming the worst."  (That would be a standard form.)

Comment: "full OED" - [Oxford English Dictionary](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/149514?redirectedFrom=pre-assume#eid). But the annual subscription is something like £150pa unless you can get free access through your educational establishment (or public library, in the UK).

Comment: @FumbleFingers Yes, good for people here to know that they can get free access to OED through their public library. (i.e. free access at home!) And the more people that do, the more power to public libraries!

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore.: Absolutely. But I must admit I tend to assume people who ask questions here don't actually live in the UK (if they *do*, they should simply interact more with native speakers in real life - that's by far the best way to learn a language). And even if you have access to UK public library login credentials, I seem to remember the OED website gets a bit sniffy if I try to access it while I'm behind an overseas-based VPN server, as sometimes happens.

Comment: OED is not subscripted by most of north American institutions, unfortunately.